# Android - intent to record video on lowest quality

Tags: android, video, android-intent, mediarecorder, mediastore

I have a project where the user can take pictures and videos without limitation of time, so i need to record with the lowest quality.

This is my code:

```
  Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
         takeVideoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);

            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            }
```

in (MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);) i made low quality

But the problem is still recording video at 2.5MB per second

So after research, I found a way to save a lower quality via MediaRecorder
but any ways I found were through SurfaceView

and i need to this project make intent are pass to original camera recorder via android

What is the best way to save a low-quality video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> did you know what is best way to save a low quality through interface of Android? more than my code?

What you have is as good as you are going to get, given that you are insisting that you must use a third-party video capture app.

It is up to the developers of the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` apps as to what the bitrate will be. Those developers do not have to honor `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY`, and even if they do, their interpretation of "low" may differ from yours. And, since there are countless pre-installed camera apps on devices, the behavior your experience will vary from device to device.

Comment: If I do it through MediaRecorder? 

I know I can not do it through the interface of Android but if I do it through 
MediaRecorder it will improve the situation?

Comment: I have no idea, as I do not know what "can not do it through the interface of Android" means. In general, you have more control with MediaRecorder.