# How do I convert video to usable quality using an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video-processing, android-camera-intent, video-compression

On my Android device I can take videos one of 2 ways:

1) I can write a custom class / set of methods that will allow me to utilize the camera and have direct control over the features

*or*

2) I can use an intent to open the video and take a recording.

This question is with regards to the latter (using an intent). This is the intent code I am using to take a video:

```
private void takeVideo(Activity activity, Context context){

        //Actual intent used to capture the video
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        //30 Second time limit (can make it anything, just using 30 here)
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);

        //Utility method I have for generating a uri to use for the video
        android.net.Uri myUri = generateVideoUri(context);

        //Uri to use
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, myUri);

        //Cap it at 20mb
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 20000000L);

        //HERE IS WHERE MY QUESTION LIES //0 is low, 1 is high
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); 
        activity.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, 100);

}
```

The above code works just fine. My question is surrounding the quality.

If I send in 0 as the quality, it is absolutely horrible quality (IE, 10 seconds of video is about 0.3mb and appears to be the lowest quality the phone can handle). If I send in 1 as the quality, it is ungodly large and unwieldy (IE, 10 seconds of video is about 50mb).

Bearing in mind that [some phone makers will ignore the intent extras sent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690398/2480714), How do I go about getting medium quality video to use for uploads, messaging, etc?

- Do I need to run some sort of compression on the large files?
- Can this only be done via a custom video/ camera class?
- Is there some other way I am not thinking of?

What would you recommend I do to get a "medium quality" video as opposed to the 2 extremes of way too large or way too small?

Thanks all!

Comment: "Do I need to run some sort of compression on the large files?" -- video files are already compressed. You would need to reduce the resolution (or possibly the frame rate). I think that there ways to do this on newer devices through `MediaCodec`, or you can try to get `ffmpeg` going, but neither is likely to be easy or fast. "Can this only be done via a custom video/ camera class?" -- that would be the only way to record in a resolution that you choose from the outset.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. Having had mixed experiences with compatibility when I wrote a custom camera class (IE HTC phones never worked right and some newer samsung phones crashed but not older ones), I am hesitant to jump into a video class in the same light. Do you have any tutorial or sample recommendations that you think would be a good starting point?

Comment: "I am hesitant to jump into a video class in the same light" -- I feel your pain. The simplest thing to do is to play around with [my CWAC-Cam2 library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2), to see if the general approach is acceptable. It's designed to be a drop-in replacement for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`/`ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` with a modest level of additional configurability. If the library seems OK, [file an enhancement request](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues) for more flexible resolution options (citing this SO question, if you think of it).

Comment: I shall do that, thanks for the help Commons!